# Booting Linux - disable need for required login

Tags: linux

Is it possible to disable the requirement for a user to login when our SVN server is booted up?  Is this a stupid risk to take?  Is it a risk?  It's accessible via the internet, but only through a custom port and only on SSL which requires user authentication.

Comment: Why would you need to log in when booting up?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  I'd suggest updating it to prevent risk of closure.

Comment: Which linux distro do you use and why exactly do you need some user to login after boot? Starting SVN server after boot without user being logged in is common practice.

Comment: What you are saying: somebody has to login at a specific point during boot because of an unusual requirement in your startup?

Comment: Are you saying "should a user be able to login for to our server without a username and password?". If so, do you mean use svn without a username and password? Ssh in without a username and password? Or still using usernames but not passwords?

Comment: I like how I got a "-1" for "is this possible"... I would think that person would post a reason why NOT to do that and then let people vote it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely sure this is your case; since you mentioned SSL, I am going to assume that the private key associated with your SSL certificate has a passphrase set, and when you boot the system you have to enter the passphrase for that key before the webserver will start.

If that is the case, you have a couple options to remove the passphrase.  You can regenerate the key, which would require regenerating any cert associtated with that key, or you can remove the password using an openssl command like:

```
openssl rsa -in /path/to/your/passworded.key -out /path/to/your/non-passworded.key
```

If you replace your existing key with the non-passworded.key, you should then be able to reboot and not have to enter the password for the key.

Comment: Seems like a good guess what the original question is asking about ...

Comment: This is right on.... I can't afford to be wrong with the SSL stuff.... will that command work?

Comment: I verified this on a test box before I posted, so it should work.  I would certainly back up the original key and keep it in an alternate location just to be sure you can always get back to what you have now.  The command I wrote in the answer doesn't overwrite your original key, so it should be safe to execute as written.  Then rename the keyfiles.